# setState from the function in external file React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider this:

```
import { someFunc } from "./someFunc";

const Container = () => {
    const [containerState, setContainerState] = useReducer(
    (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }),
    { value: "", text: "some text here" });
    // I want to move the function bellow into external file (see the "import" above)
    // const someFunc = () => {
    //    setContainerState({value: "string"})
    // }
    // like this:
    // const extFunc = someFunc();
    // useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    //     someFunc()
    // }));
    // but if I do so, I'll get "setContainerState" is undefined
    // how can I move this function to external file?
    // it is long and it makes my component messy and hard to read
    return (
        <h1>Test Title</h1>
        <button onClick={someFunc}>click me</button>
    )
}
```

I saw some similar questions/answers here, but with the `Class` components, but how can setState like this with Hooks?

PS: I need to use useImperativeHandle to implement my other logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the function, but you'll have to pass `setContainerValue` into it as a parameter:

```
export const someFunc(setContainerState => {
    setContainerState({value: "string"});
};
```

There's no need for `useImperativeHandle`, just call `someFunc` directly in `Container`.

Comment: does this method safe if I use `useReducer` to handle state changes for the `setContainerState` inside the `Container` component?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thank you

Comment: @jay_dtr - Yes, it should be fine. What matters is that the hooks get called during the call to your component. It's okay if it's because your component called a function that called the hook.